# possibility of music notation rendering for android

Tags: java, android

I am looking for rendering musical scores in Android. 
So far I have just been able to find 2 GPL libraries namely abcj and Jmusic both of which support java.While specifying it in any android's class path application throws up exception this might be possible as Android doesn't support javaSE environment java's byte code differs from Android's dalvik code.. can I somehow get these libraries to work for my android app or are there any 3rd party API's available for Android development ..?

Comment: Do you have the source code for the libraries?

Comment: both of them are open source projects so yes source code is available.

Comment: So, try to compile the Java sources to dalvik and see what breaks ;)

Comment: i didn't get u could u explain in detail..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a thesis on "Dynamic Generation of Musical Notation from MusicXML Input on an Android Tablet"
https://etd.ohiolink.edu/rws_etd/document/get/osu1338377470/inline

9/20/20: That link is broken, this one appears to work: https://etd.ohiolink.edu/!etd.send_file?accession=osu1338377470&disposition=inline

Answer (score -1):

This open source library has experimental implementations for Android using Xamarin:
http://musicengravingcontrols.com/